# compiling pattern inside another pattern using python regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to compile python regex inside another regex. for example find IP address like this below: 
This does not seem to work.

```
 >>> import re 
    >>> p_ip = re.compile(r'[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5]')
    >>> p_ip_full =re.compile( r'^(p_ip)\.{3}p_ip$')
    >>> ip_str = "255.123.123.12"
    >>> if (p_ip_full.match(ip_str)):
    ...     print("match")
    ...
    >>> p_ip_full
    re.compile('^(p_ip)\\.{3}p_ip$')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `p_ip` is simply looking for the literal characters `p_ip`. Use `.format()` to add the value in. You don't even need to wrap the first part in a `re.compile`, treat it as a normal string.

```
p_ip = r'[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-5][0-5]'
p_ip_full = re.compile(r'^({0})\.{{3}}{0}$'.format(p_ip))
```

Note that you need to encase `{3}` in a double `{{ }}` so it gets escaped.